# Automatically setup a AWS Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, automation, continuous-integration

I wanted to know if there is a way to setup a cloud environment using Amazon Web Services automatically (like by just invoking a batch file...). 
I have a scenario where i want to setup the Environment with all the requisite things like OS, Platforms etc. I want to automate the entire process of setting up the environment. Is this possible?
I am trying to do Continuous Integration and as a part of CI i want to first set up the environment for the application to be deployed, deploy the application and then run automated and performance tests. i am using Jenkins to run my automated and performance test cases with Selenium and Jmeter. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different tools based on your requirement.

- If you also want to configure VPC and other network level configuration, you can use cloud formation, basically you'll create a template and launch your infrastructure using this template file.
  https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/[cloufformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)
- if you need to launch an project with a database, application server (tomcat, java, python, ...) and with load balancing and autoscaling configuration, you can use elasticbeanstalk 
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html
- opswork, docker could be also an option depending on your requirements. But they need pre configuration.

Would be more easy to advise a solution if you extend question with your use case.